# Delphi System.Zip xlsx LibreOffice

Tags: excel, delphi, zip, xlsx, libreoffice

My system is WIN7 64 and I use a Delphi XE7 component to create .xlsx files. An example [result file](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/attachment.cgi?id=115970).

The files can be opened with MS Office (no problem), but with LibreOffice I can't because I have this error: "The file is corrupted and can't be openend ...". Suspicion is that System.Zip somehow wrongly packs files.

LibreOffice Calc doesn't show any detail information about why it can't open my files. I don't see how to start to itemize the problem.

To understand the reason for it is in archiving method, I did the following.
Unpacked the file and packed it again using WinRar.
Rename it to *.xlsx and vuala.

Now  can open it.

Here is the new repacked file
https://yadi.sk/i/bSr6g8xDh3Yde

Comment: @pnuts rather for the said component technical support

Comment: ты.. это... или не умничай... или умничай со словарем!  французское слово пишется "voila", а так... ну это как на заборе слово из трех букв с ошибками писать - лучше не писать вообще, чем позориться :-D

Comment: Try a different zip library. Say tpAbbrevia.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yep, different zipping engine would perhaps be more permissive :-) I remember i made a similar mistake with RTL ZIP, not reading zip specifications and not providing correct data for it :-)

Comment: @DmitryB please show me the code that stores an file of XLSX internals into the zip, i want to see your bridging, here there is an XML content in some array or stream, and here you put it into your ZIP file with some settings, i want to see this code of yours, i think i know what you forgot to do. Alternatively, why would not you just utilize some ODS/XLSX generator instead of inventing your own brand new bicycle and making your way through the traps people already passed through ?

Comment: The code is not so linear that I could copy all of it here.
Here are sections that relate to TZipFile object.

    FStream:  TFileStream;
    FZipFile: TZipFile;
    Data: TStringStream;


  FStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
...
  FZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
  FZipFile.Open(FStream, zmWrite);

...
// Data := New MemoryStream for theme1.xml
// Fill Data 
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\theme\theme1.xml');

Comment: ...
// Data := New TStringStream for .rels
  FZipFile.Add(Data, '_rels\.rels');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'docProps\app.xml');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'docProps\core.xml');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\_rels\workbook.xml.rels');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\workbook.xml');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, '[Content_Types].xml');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml');
..
  FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\styles.xml');
..
  FZipFile.Close;
  FreeAndNil(FZipFile);
  FreeAndNil(FStream);

Comment: updated the answer // also please next time to do not conceal information. I spent an hour making a running Linux computer just to check the 10% of information that you already had week ago in LibreOffice bugtracker. That my time was just wasted!

Comment: I think it would be polite if you would check my solution and if it works, you would report at Libre bug-tracker what exactly was wrong with your xlsx and how you fixed it and then close the ticket there. Then in future some another guy with a same mistake would be able to find your ticket and understand his trouble from your summary. http://maddog.sitengine.ru/smart-question-ru.html#followup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i used XE2 System.Zip to create both ODS and XLSX  and OpenOffice.org opens them fine

can you ask your xlsx-generating component to use another zip engine ?

*Now that the topic starter reported he made zip repack and uploaded both files to compare - I removed most part of my answer*

---

since you did the repacking test...

I confirm one of two files fail to open on OpenOffice 4.1.1 Win32 and LibreOffice 4.2 Linux

Libreoffice writes the following error:

```
libreoffice4.2 ./Export.xlsx 
:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
```

more info on error is at https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91579

_

Under Windows there is no way to get a error log, except maybe installing cygwin, which I do not have.

---

Okay, I think I remember it now. I guess I made a similar mistake two years ago... But - if that hypothesis holds true - I managed to read zip format spec and fix it. Many commercial zip libs knew about this lapse of newbs and fixed this mistake silently. But System.Zip works verbatim as you told it to, so it propagates your mistake into the XLSX file as is.

That is my idea, but StackOverflow is the programmers' site, so I ask you to show us all your code, your implementation of content storing. So we should be able to check your code and see

I ask you to show us the code you use between XMLs generators and System.Zip packer, when you got some spreashsheet in some buffer - how exactly do you put it into the zip-xlsx file ?

My code is here ( exactly implementation of storing generated content into the zip file ) if you care: https://github.com/the-Arioch/avemey.com/tree/master/zexmlss

---

Topic starter added:

```
 FZipFile.Add(Data, 'xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml');
```

Gotcha! - here you violate ZIP format specification. Looking back at my lib source above and its name fixing...

- you should use normal slashes "/", not back-slashes "\"
- you should not start filename with a slash like '/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml'
- you should not use two slashes together like 'xl//worksheets//sheet1.xml'

u violate #1, you do not seem to violate #2 and #3 but keep them in mind to not fall for it in the future.

Opening file from disk is permissive to these quirks and fixes them on the go, but zip parsers usually are not.

Also please think about co-developing a common everyone's library rather than making your own ad hoc one and fighting all the problems alone.

Comment: If to repack files using for example WinRar then LibreOffice Calc can open it.
If think there are some parameters in System.Zip to customize packing process.

Comment: > you should use normal slashes "/", not back-slashes "\"

Yes. It works. Thank you.